# while loop in database

Tags: java, mysql, while-loop

I'm trying to create an application that check if the "username" and "password" that the user will insert are correct and do exist in "mysql" database so that's the code

```
while(rs.next()){

    boolean a=false;

    String un=rs.getString("UserName");
    String pass=rs.getString("PassWord");

    if(un.equals(username) && pass.equals(password)) {                  
        a=true;
        break;
    } else {
        a=false;
    }      
}
```

The problem now is that it works well if and only if I entered the first username and password in the database ... otherwise it gives me errors

Comment: Your query should pass the username so you only need one row, also you **really** shouldn't store user passwords in plaintext.

Comment: It looks like you are grabbing all rows from your user table and then comparing each row to the inputted username/password... That seems like a lot of useless work. You should take the inputted username/password and do a select on your database where username/password = the given parameters. that way if a single row is returned then you have an okay to log in

Comment: take both username and password .then check do both match.SELECT * FROM `users` where name='"+user+"' and pass='"+pass+"'"